# Taking $\inf$ for sobolev space in different order

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ open bounded, smooth boundary be given. Define
$$
F(u,v):=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2v^2dx+\int_\Omega(|\nabla v|^2+(1-v)^2)dx,
$$
and two sets $\mathcal U:=\{u\in H^1(\Omega),\,T[u]=T[w]\}$, where $w\in H^1(\Omega)$ is a fixed function. Also, $\mathcal V:=\{v\in H^1(\Omega),\,\,0\leq v\leq 1\}$.

My question: does it hold that ?
$$
\operatorname{argmin}_{v\in\mathcal V}\operatorname{argmin}_{u\in\mathcal U} F(u,v) = \operatorname{argmin}_{u\in\mathcal U} \operatorname{argmin}_{v\in\mathcal V}F(u,v)
$$
Clearly the $\inf$ exists on the both hand side, but I am not sure whether they are equal...

Answer (score 1):

If one of them exists, the other does, too, and both are equal. This follows by using just general properties of infima. Both sides equal 
$$ \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) $$
since clearly, given $u$, we have
$$ \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) \le \inf_v F(u,v) $$
so,
$$ \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) \le \inf_u \inf_v F(u,v) $$
On the other side, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $u',v'$ with $F(u',v') \le \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) + \epsilon$. Then 
$$ \inf_v F(u',v) \le F(u',v') $$
and hence
$$ \inf_u \inf_v F(u,v) \le F(u',v') \le \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) + \epsilon $$
As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, 
$$ \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) = \inf_u \inf_v F(u,v)$$
As the left hand side is symmetric in $u,v$, we have analogously, 
$$  \inf_{u,v} F(u,v) = \inf_v \inf_u F(u,v)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I vote it up for clear explanation. However, I found an error in my post which makes the question looks pretty different...